# python and pip not in sync

Tags: bash, python3, pip

I installed ubuntu16.04 today and automatically went and installed python from their website.

Now I have python3.5 preinstalled in `usr/bin` and python3.6 installed in `usr/local/bin`.

When I type in `pip3 -V` in bash i get:

> pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)

When i type in `python3 -V` i get:

> Python 3.6.5

So everything I do with pip3, wont follow through to python3.

How can I fix this?

I cant find how to uninstall just python3.6.

I tried making an alias for python3 in the hope itd overwrite it, it didnt.

I haven tried changing PATH order, I dont know how and if it would even fix it.

Also, apt-get remove python3.6 doesnt work, since it was installed via the browser.

I hope I provided enough info. Id be happy to provide more if needed

Comment: I solved it. First I removed 'python3' from the python3.6 folder. I also re-added `/usr/bin` to the PATH. One of those did the job I'm not sure which, but I think the latter. I can still use python 3.6 though by typing `python3.6` into bash. My default python is again 3.5 and that's the one where pip3 was working.

Comment: @dessert that's exactly what I did, but it did nothing, contrary to what online sources told me it would.

Comment: @MarkRensen Please add an answer explaining your solution below.